# mMap.clear in some other function is removing marker from public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng)?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-markers

so i have a function

```
 public void centerOnMapLocation (Location location, String title) {

        if (location != null) {
            LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(title));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 13));
        }
    }
```

in android map activity and i implemented onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng)

```
  @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

        String addressTitle = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            ArrayList<Address> addressArrayList = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.latitude, 1);

            if (addressArrayList != null & addressArrayList.size() > 0) {
                if (addressArrayList.get(0).getAddressLine(0) != null) {

                    addressTitle += addressArrayList.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(addressTitle));

    }
```

in maps activity and inside the function i added a marker . but on long click the marker vanishes and when i remove
" mMap.clear() " from the previous function "centerOnMapLocation" then I'm able to add back the marker and it stays there .

My question is I'm not even calling that function in onMapLongClick but when i remove mMap.clear(); from the other function . I'm able to add markers inside it ?? What I'm doing wrong

Comment: `centerOnMapLocation` is being called somewhere in your code - likely on a position update.  Search on it or show references if in studio.

Comment: yes it's being called on "location change listener" but how it's affecting a totally different function ?

Comment: Because there is only one global map in an application - so a `mMap.clear()` anywhere in your app will remove all markers from the one map.